# How do I build stack configuration that allows me to build project with reflex-frp as dependency?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, reflex

As in question. I can't get working stack configuration. I want to build project that uses reflex with ghc, preferably 8.0.2 or higher.
How do I do it, cause specifying it as an extra deps doesn't seem to work either..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like no published version of `reflex` supports ghc 8.0.2.  There are a lot of changes on the `develop` branch since the 0.4 release: https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/compare/cc62c11a6cde31412582758c236919d4bb766ada...develop

So first I tried this:

```
resolver: lts-9.5

packages:
- .
- location:
    git: https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex
    commit: 916c876
  extra-dep: true
```

But that led to:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

   In the dependencies for reflex-0.5.0:
       prim-uniq must match >=0.1.0.1 && <0.2, but the stack configuration has no specified version
                 (latest applicable is 0.1.0.1)
       ref-tf must match ==0.4.*, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.4.0.1)
   needed due to hmm-0.1.0.0 -> reflex-0.5.0

   Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /home/mgsloan/fpco/test-stack/stackoverflow46391975/hmm/stack.yaml:
   - prim-uniq-0.1.0.1
   - ref-tf-0.4.0.1
```

Following the recommended action yields a configuration that works:

```
resolver: lts-9.5

packages:
- .
- location:
    git: https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex
    commit: 916c876
  extra-dep: true

extra-deps:
- prim-uniq-0.1.0.1
- ref-tf-0.4.0.1
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but apparently I must have done something a bit different, for example apart from specifying reflex in packages I also put it in extra-deps.. lol
Anyways.. it worked! Thank you :)