# Broken dependency in haskell stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, reflex, stackage

I am relatively new to haskell, stack, ghc, etc.

Have been trying a few projects with ghcjs and haven't been able to build any of them, including [reflex-dom-stack-demo](https://github.com/reinh/reflex-dom-stack-demo). I am getting the following error:

```
In the dependencies for semigroupoids-5.0.0.4:             
    tagged-0.8.1 from stack configuration does not match >=0.8.5 && <1 (latest matching version is 0.8.5)              
needed due to ghcjs-0.2.0 -> semigroupoids-5.0.0.4
```

Now I cannot understand whether I misconfigured something or there is truly a broken dependency. Deleted `~/.stack` multiple times throughout my experiments.

I found [this bug in stackage](https://github.com/fpco/stackage/issues/3185)  but am unsure whether this is what affects me, and whether it would be fixed once the fix moves through.

Using Ubuntu 17.10..

Any insight is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recomended way to create a development environnement for reflex-dom is to use [try-reflex](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform).

It is tricky to build reflex-dom with stack, because some needed changes have not yet been added to the upstream libraries.

If you really want to build a reflex-dom environnement with stack, please consider these hints:

- Do not use a GHC compiler with a version higher than 8.0.2
- Do not use the reflex /reflex-dom versions from Hackage, they are outdated.
- Use versions of reflex / reflex-dom from Github.
- [This repo](https://github.com/hansroland/reflex-dom-inbits) contains a stack.yaml file, that used to work.
- You may also try the stack.yaml file from the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391975/how-do-i-build-stack-configuration-that-allows-me-to-build-project-with-reflex-f).